# Cache values of window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript, browser

To prevent layout thrashing I want to cache the values of window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth. Am I correct in assuming that this module:

```
module.exports = {
  h: window.innerHeight,
  w: window.innerWidth
};
```

When browserified, will access window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth everytime the properties are used, but that the below module:

```
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

module.exports = {
  h: windowHeight,
  w: windowWidth
};
```

Will only access window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth once? Even when the exported properties are accessed multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are right... I think both your examples will cache the values.

Module code is indeed run when an app is started, and just made available using `require`. It is not re-run at each `require`. If you want non-cached values, you'll have to put them in a method, something like:

```
module.exports = {
    cachedH: window.innerHeight, // will not change

    calculatedH: function() {
        return window.innerHeight; // will recalculate each time called
    }
};
```

Comment: Won't the properties in the first example just be passed as a reference instead of as a value?

Comment: You could prove me wrong, but I don't think so. I've been bit by that with trying set dates to the current time, and they keep returning the time my app started.

Comment: @vsjn no, numbers are always passed by value.